# DLookup in Access not running until textBox clicked on in Form

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I'm setting 12 TextBox ControlSources in my Form from VBA using the following :

```
...
Me.Oct.ControlSource = "=DSum('GBPValue', 'MF YTD Actual Income & Adret', 'Month=10 AND Org_Type=[Key]')"
Me.Nov.ControlSource = "=DSum('GBPValue', 'MF YTD Actual Income & Adret', 'Month=11 AND Org_Type=[Key]')"
...
```

[Key] is the name of a textbox in the form

When the form loads up i get some odd behavior -

- all of the summary form text boxes are blank as are all the dlookup text boxes

  if i then click on one of the text boxes that has a dlookup control source assigned the summary text boxes for the other columns start to populate with 0's and #Num etc. and the dlookup runs and displays the expected numbers

  once i've clicked on all the dlookup fields the summary numbers calc properly.

In the final version of this the query will be re-written after user clicks from the VBA so ... is this a sensible way to get the form to re-query the DB and, if so, how can i make the DLookups run/display automatically so that everything displays immediately on form load?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably looking for Recalc (Me.Recalc). However, I suggest you use a recordset, rather than DlookUp, and the Current event for the form:

```vb
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset 'Needs MS DAO 3.x library
Dim db As Database
Dim strSQL As String

Set db = CurrentDb()

'Guessing that key is a form value
'Note that Month is a reserved word

strSQL = "SELECT [Month], Sum(GBPValue) As SumVal " _
       & "FROM [MF YTD Actual Income & Adret] " _
       & "WHERE Org_Type= " & Me.[Key]  
       & " GROUP BY [Month]" 

Set rs=db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)

'You can probably use a Do While Loop, consider 
'naming the controls, eg, Month10

rs.FindFirst "[Month]=10" 
Me.Oct = rs!SumVal

'and so on
```

Comment: thank-you for this ... i got it working with Recalc after much confusing playing around trying to get the recordSet method to work -will be posting the problem i ran into as a separate question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479640/vba-access-recordset-per-form-record-problem), thanks again!

Comment: I've gone back to adding in a load of DSums given the complexity of any other solution, the only problem i have with this approach is that only the text boxes that are currently on-screen are displayed once the Recalc runs, the others have been calc-d but are only displayed once i click into that text-box. This form is ~2x a 1024px LCD wide. I tried playing around with multiple REcalcs and moving the focus in between which nearly works but seems really kludgy - is there a better way?

Comment: above should be another question i guess - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1496072/after-me-recalc-in-access-off-screen-values-are-not-displayed

Comment: With a continuous form, any unbound control that depends on the current record for data will display the result for the current record on all rows of the form - all unbound controls will display the same data, but it may change according to the current record.