# VBA/Access RecordSet per form record problem

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007, recordset

I'm new to VBA and Access in general and ran into this problem whilst trying to use the proposed alternate implementation from another question I'd asked ([DLookup in Access not running until textBox clicked on in Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1476030/dlookup-in-access-not-running-until-textbox-clicked-on-in-form))

The code below runs, the issue is that Me.Key is different for each record being displayed in the form and running this in the form open event means it grabs only the first value assigned to Me.Key from the first record. How can i make this run so that Me.Key is different for each record/line being displayed?

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim db As Database
Dim qdf As QueryDef
Dim prm As Parameter

Set db = CurrentDb
Set qdf = db.QueryDefs("[MF INCOME - STREAM MONTHLY]")
For Each prm In qdf.Parameters
    prm.Value = Eval(prm.Name)
Next prm

Set rs = qdf.OpenRecordset(dbOpenDynaset)
rs.FindFirst "[MyMonth]=10 AND [Org_Type]='" & Me.Key & "'"
Me.Oct = rs!SumVal
'...other month assignments
```

Comment: You can navigate through the form's records via recordset navigation. But I would suggest that you might consider whether it's better to open the recordset once and navigate via .FindFirst or if it's better to open your records limited to the records for each row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the Me.Key refers to a control located in the details section of your form. In this case, and in order to list all values taken by the control, you will need to browse all the records. One of the ways to do so can be:

```
Dim m_position as Long
for m_position = 1 to Me.recordset.recordcount
   me.seltop = m_position
   debug.print me.key
next m_position
```

Unfortunately your will see your screen blincker while browsing all the lines. You can off course find some 'screenFreezer' utilities for VBA on the net (there is one called LockWindowUpdate, as long as I can remember).

Another solution is to browse the clone of the underlying recordset (browsing the recordset will provoke the same screen behaviour as before). Supposing that the Me.Key control is bound to the "Key" column of the recordset, code could be:

```
Dim rsClone as DAO.recordset
set rsClone = Me.recordsetclone
if rsClone.EOF and rsClone.BOF then
Else
    rsClone.moveFirst
    Do while not rsClone.EOF
        debug.print rsCLone.fields("Key")
        rsClone.moveNext
    Loop
Endif
set rsClone = nothing
```

My favorite is the first one, with the "freeze"option added. Your code can manage the seltop and selheight values of the form. This means you can browse specifically records selected by users and/or, once all records browsed, go back to the original record selection.

EDIT:

Following @Ben's comment, I shall add that if your "myControl" control is in the details section and is unbound, you then will not be able to manage one value per row. The control will have the same value for all lines when the form is displayed as "continuous".

If your "myControl" control is bound to the "myField" field of a recordset, any of the following codes will increment  "myControl" control value and "myField" field value at the same time. You will be than able to have a different value on each row:

Solution 1:

```
Dim m_position as Long
for m_position = 1 to Me.recordset.recordcount
   me.seltop = m_position
   me.controls("myControl") = m_position
next m_position
```

Solution 2:

```
Dim rsClone as DAO.recordset, _
    i as long

set rsClone = Me.recordsetclone
if rsClone.EOF and rsClone.BOF then
Else
    rsClone.moveFirst
    i = 1
    Do while not rsClone.EOF
        rsClone.fields("myField") = i
        rsClone.update
        rsClone.moveNext
        i = i+1
    Loop
Endif
set rsClone = nothing
```

Comment: sorry for the delay in answering, other projects got in the way. This looks like it might well help ... the blinking isn't an issue for my users (small charity i'm volunteering some time at), the system replaces hundreds of post-its, spreadsheets and emails ;)

using the first solution you posted i can iterate over the different Keys and see the correct values being calculated per Key but every time Me.Oct=<x> is set every records 'Oct' field gets that same value. I've not seen SetTop before ... is there some way to use that value to set 'Oct' for just the current record?

Comment: thanks for the write-up, i think in my specific case this won't work but as a general answer to the original question it's excellent. cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the current event of the form, as suggested previously :)

Comment: it runs fine and numbers are displayed using either event ... the problem is that Me.Key is always the same value if it's run like this whereas in the form itself it's different per row. some rookie error i'm making i feel!

Comment: You talk of rows, this suggests that you are using a continuous form or datasheet, if this is the case, you will need to look at a different approach, such as setting up a query, or changing to a single form.

Comment: using a continuous form so guess i'll need to do something different, i can't use the single form approach as this form is built as a sort of navigator for the users - each row displays aggregate financial information that can be drilled down into multiple times to see (eventually) individual incomes with their dates that the charity received per project/donor/income stream. 

Is there an access-standard way to populate data per row of the form from the database based on values in that row?

Comment: I think you may need a suitable query, because the problem with continuous forms is that only bound controls will display different data for each row. Perhaps you could provide the schema for the tables from which data is to be displayed?

Comment: thankyou for all your answers on this ... by the time this query is run there are about 8 database tables, maybe 30 different columns being used so rather than spam all of that i think i'll take a good look at re-working the RecordSource query for the form to include months.

Answer (score 0):

It is not at all clear what you need the parameters for in that query. I would suggest that you simply build a query without ANY parameters that includes all of the columns you need.

Then build small form based on this query. You can then drop this small form into your existing form and display the several fields of data based on the key value setting. (just ensure that you setup the link master and child settings for the sub-form). Here what a form looks like:

[image]
<sub>(source: [shaw.ca](http://www.members.shaw.ca/AlbertKallal/Articles/invoice2.gif))</sub>

So, in the above the bill to displays the customer info based on customer id and is a related table to in invoice.

In other words to display several fields of data based on a key value from another table you don’t need to write one line of code. So this whole process and goal of yours can be done by drag and drop with the mouse. I often have something like a invoice, or purchase order and I ONLY have the customer ID. By using a sub-form I can display the whole address and several fields of data without writing any code. As you move from record to record, this whole set of fields will update and always display the correct related data.

Comment: thanks for the answer - i think this would work i it weren't for the fact that i'm displaying multiple 'keys' or multiple 'customers' in your example and i don't think i can make a continuous form have a subform.