# After Me.Recalc in Access off-screen values are not displayed

Tags: ms-access, vba

From VBA I'm setting a series of text boxes to have DSum controlSources:

```
Me.Oct.ControlSource = "=DSum('GBPValue', _
                                'MF YTD Actual Income & Adret', _
                                'Month=10 AND Org_Type=[Key]')"
Me.Nov.ControlSource = "=DSum('GBPValue', _
                                'MF YTD Actual Income & Adret', _
                                'Month=11 AND Org_Type=[Key]')"
```

and then running Me.Recalc to get the values to show up once set. This works fine for the text boxes that are on-screen when the form loads but for ones on the same (very wide) form that are not currently on screen the Recalc seems to do nothing. If I scroll across the form and select the blank fields the values then show up. Is there any way to get the values for every text box on-screen or off to be there on form load or, at worst, when the user scrolled across?

Comment: Is there some reason you don't pull the data into the recordsource of your form, simply by joining to the tables whose data you're looking up?

Comment: Hi, yes, the current recordsource query runs to about 300 lines of SQL (provides years of financial analysis across dozens of multi-million pound projects), I started re-writing this to include the per month calculations and i think it'll end up several times more massive. Given that my time has already run out on this project and the people inheriting it at the charity it's for aren't developers I wanted to leave something that was as simple to understand as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can guess why this must be happening: it's likely that Recalc doesn't repaint controls that are not currently visible.  So even though the value of the controls has in fact changed, their cached visual appearance still appears empty when the scrolling windows reveals them.

Here's what I'd recommend: create a member function on your form like this:

```
Function GetMonthValue(Month As Long) As Double
   GetMonthValue = DSum("GBPValue", "MF YTD Actual Income & Adret", _
                 "Month=" & Month & " AND Org_Type=" & [Key])
End Function
```

The control source for the text boxes can then be set to "=GetMonthValue(1)" and so on.  This means that each control's source is declared statically and there's no need to change anything when the form loads.  When the current record changes, the value should track, although I haven't verified this with testing.

Comment: I'd guess the same ... have tried this solution and it works like a charm, thank-you so much for this, have been trying to get something to work for a week! (sad but true)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the problem is but you can try this:

```
...
Me.Oct = DSum('GBPValue', _
                'MF YTD Actual Income & Adret', _
                'Month=10 AND Org_Type=[Key]')
Me.Nov = DSum('GBPValue', _
                'MF YTD Actual Income & Adret', _
                'Month=11 AND Org_Type=[Key]')
...
```

Set control's text by using `DSum` directly.

**Edit:** You can also try refreshing the form after the calculations, i.e. `Me.Refresh`.

Comment: this is on a continuous form where Key is a value in the details section of the form so i think i'm stuck with setting the controlsource - if i try to set it directly form vba it sets the column to the same value based on whatever the last 'Key' is (i think ... novice to VBA/Access !)